How to turn off the screen without stopping calculations on Linux Mint?
I have a distribution
Linux Mint 20
Ulyana
I wanted to keep my calculations (which last several hours, even several days) running while turning off the screen without stopping my PC.
In other words, is it possible to turn off only the screen, like during a logout, while allowing the calculations to continue?
Thus, only I, with my password, would be able to access the session.
I tried screen, with screen -n command line but I am looking for another automatic solution if it is possible?

New Linux Users tend to forget that the Desktop Environment is separate from the actual terminal.  Start the system as normal, login as your user into the Cinnamon Session.  After doing so, press Ctrl + Alt + F<n> where n !=1 or 7. 1 is the primary terminal, i.e. the system booted from there, 7 and sometimes 8 is the terminal that the Wayland/X Session is using. After choosing a blank terminal, login again and start your calculations on that terminal. Switching between the X Session terminal and the calculation terminal is now possible.

Use the actual screensaver in settings.  It has black screen and it has password on resume.
